# ADF: How to Convert a datetime column (AM/PM) to UTC format?

Tags: azure, timestamp, azure-data-factory

I have a column where timestamp is `5/23/2022 8:45:34 PM`. I want to create a new column with same data as old column but in UTC format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' and this new datetime format is 7 hours behind UTC (UTC-7)

I tried doing in azure data factory derived column using `toTimestamp` before it converts to UTC but it always fail.

> toTimestamp(column_name,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS')

but it did not work and the result always NULL.

Can anyone help this data conversion to UTC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting null values for the newly added columns is because the format you specified in the `toTimestamp()` function is incorrect. The following is the sample data that I used to reproduce this issue. The `date` column here is of type `String`.

[image]

While using `Derived column` in the dataflow to create a new date column of `timestamp` type, write `toTimestamp(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'UTC')`  expression as the value for this new column. Here, date is the column you want to convert to new date column and `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a` is the format of the values in `date` column (`a` represents the AM/PM). You can also pass time zone value like `UTC`, `GMT` etc. which is **optional**.

[image]

The following is what the result looks like, with a new column of `timestamp` type. You can use this resulting data to perform further conversions in dataflow.

[image]

Comment: yeah, you're right. My time format was wrong and I've already changed it.